# jquery mobile animate height when tap list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm making a expandable list with Jquery.

this is my example here http://jsfiddle.net/z253w/

```
<style>
.showDetail { height:30px }
</style>

<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-inset="true" class="recentList">
            <li id="recentCall1" class="menu-item">
                <a href="#" class="showDetail"> 
                    <h2>Title</h2> 
                    <div class="detail">detail Text</div>
                </a>
                <a class="btnDelList" href="#">Delete</a> 
            </li>
            <li id="recentCall2" class="menu-item">
                <a href="#" class="showDetail"> 
                    <h2>Title</h2> 
                    <div class="detail">detail Text</div>
                </a>
                <a class="btnDelList" href="#">Delete</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
        <script> 
        var li = '';
        $(document.body).on('click', '.btnDelList' ,function(){
            li = $(this).parent();
            $('#popDel').popup("open");
        });

        $(document.body).on('click', '#okDel' ,function(){
            $('#popDel').popup("close");
            li.remove();
        });

        $(document.body).on('click', '#noDel' ,function(){
            $('#popDel').popup("close");
        });
        </script>

        <div data-role="popup" id="popDel" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px; padding-bottom:2em;">
            <h3>Delete product?</h3>
            <p>Do you want to remove this product from the list?</p>
            <input id="okDel" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="check" type="button" value="Delete!" />
            <input id="noDel" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="delete" type="button" value="No" />
        </div>
```

How do I make ".showDetail" to animate height:100px when tap it?  (default height is 30px)

I could not use Collapsible Module on JQM. Because it's hard to combine the delete item script.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery [.animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method for this.
get your `.showDetail` height in javascript variable like below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    showHeight = $(".showDetail").height();
});
```

and check the height while click on the element, then animate it like below,

```
$(".showDetail").on("tap", function () {
    if ($(this).height() == showHeight) $(this).animate({
        height: "100px"
    }, "fast");
    else $(this).animate({
        height: showHeight
    }, "fast");
});
```

**SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/gC5Je/)**

Comment: great!! Solved problem. Thank you~